# AngularJS custom filter for Pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have implemented the following filter(`startFrom`) in my `app.js` file:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function () {
        return function (input, start) {
            start = +start;
            return input.slice(start);
        }
    });
```

I revice the data in an asychroneous way and the filter is applied at page load.
The problem is that the data is not available when the filter is used.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="hotel in hotels | filter:search | startFrom:currentPage*itemsPerPage | orderBy:sortBy.Name :order.reverse | limitTo:itemsPerPage">
```

How can I have filter applied after the data is available?

Comment: I strongly recommend getting the back end endpoint to return paginated data rather than trying to do this from the front end.

Answer (score 0):

"A filter should always check the validity of its input.
The input might be the result of an async operation,
so the filter can't be sure the input is always what
it's expecting for when it is being evaluated."

Accordingly to words try this

```
 app.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        if (!angular.isArray(input)) {
            return [];
        }
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

You haven't written but try to use only search and pagination filter, sometimes others filters can be the issue, so then you are sure that the problem is in your pagination filter.